# AWS Security Group Outbound Query

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to AWS doc, it is not required to put port 22 in outbound even though it is mentioned in inbound.

Should not the port be mentioned in both? If not then why is it so?

Comment: By default AWS Security Groups have all outbound ports open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opposite direction rule is not required, because security groups are stateful -- they "remember" what connections are open and they allow bidirectional traffic for the duration of the connection (or until the state table entry times out due to no activity and no keepalives). They are not simple, stateless ACLs.  If a security group allows an inbound connection to port 22, it will automatically allow the outbound response packets from port 22 matching the already-established connection.  Similarly, inbound responses to outbound requests are also automatically allowed.

From the docs:

> Security groups are stateful — if you send a request from your instance, the response traffic for that request is allowed to flow in regardless of inbound security group rules. **Responses to allowed inbound traffic are allowed to flow out, regardless of outbound rules.** *(emphasis added)*
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html